# C++ how can I simplify this if else statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, coding-style

I would like to know how I could simplify a statement like the one below.

I have similar code everywhere, and would like to clear it up.

```
if(isActive)
{
    if(columnId == 4)
        g.drawText(active[row].value, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centredLeft, true);
}
else
{
    if(columnId == 4)
        g.drawText(inactive[row].value, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centredLeft, true);
}
```

`isActive`, as you can imagine, is a `bool` value.

Comment: `if(columnId == 4) { g.drawText(isActive ? active[row].value : inactive[row].value, ...);  }`?

Comment: `auto value_to_pass = isActive? active[row].value : inactive[row].value; g.drawText(value_to_pass, ...);`

Comment: Assuming `active` and `inactive` have the same type .... `if (column[Id == 4) {auto thing = (isActive ? active : inactive)[row].value; g.drawText(thing, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centred);}` or even `if (columnID == 4) g.drawText((isActive : active : inActive)[row].value, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centred);`.     Some folks will debate how readable this is though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, it's most apparent that this code only does anything if `columnId == 4`.

```
if(columnId == 4)
{
    if(isActive)
    {
        g.drawText(active[row].value, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centredLeft, true);
    }
    else
    {
        g.drawText(inactive[row].value, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centredLeft, true);
    }
}
```

At second glance, those two bulky lines are almost the same.

```
if(columnId == 4)
{
    auto & text = isActive ? active : inactive;
    g.drawText(text[row].value, 2, 0, width, height, Justification::centredLeft, true);
}
```

Note, also, the valid comment from @eerorika.  ⬇️  I couldn't say it better than they did.

Comment: Note that the latter form requires `active` and `inactive` to have the same type. It may likely be so in this case, but it's an important detail to understand when considering this transformation in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (columnId != 4)
    ; // do nothing
else if (isActive)
    . . .
else
    . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda could be used to simplify the original code structure, by reducing the amount of duplicated text.

```
auto drawText = [&](auto &table) {
    g.drawText(table[row].value, 2, 0, width, height,
               Justification::centeredLeft, true);
};

if(isActive)
{
    if(columnId == 4) drawText(active);
}
else
{
    if(columnId == 4) drawText(inactive);
}
```